# The Emacs eshell alias of CMake doesn't recognize path correctly?

Tags: eshell, aliases

I'm using the Emacs eshell's alias feature to make an alias to the `cmake` command like below:

```
$ alias cmake 'cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1'
```

The alias is created correctly, here is the output of running `which cmake` inside eshell:

```
$ which cmake
cmake is an alias, defined as "cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1"
```

However, when running this alias `cmake` inside my project, it doesn't recognize the input path correctly. For example, when running `cmake ..`, it seems unable to interpret the `..` path.

Here are the detailed steps to produce this error:

```
$ cd my-project     # the CMakeLists.txt is stored at the root folder of this project
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..          # running the cmake alias
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Error: The source directory "/home/trungtq/workspace/ocaml/discover/llvm-normalizer/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the arguments in the Eshell alias as `$1`, `$2`, ... or as full list of provided arguments `$*`. See the [documentation of Eshell `aliases`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Aliases.html).

In your special case you could use:

```sh
alias cmake 'cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 $*'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip! I realized that previously I also used the arguments `$*`, `$1`, but enclosed the alias definition in the double quote `"..."`, hence it didn't work. But somehow, when posting the question, I used the single quote `'...'` :-D